# How to remove or replace callbacks for a specific path

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to replace the `/` path with another callback:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('404'))
```

But when I navigate to `/` path it still responds with `Hello World!` instead of `404`, so that means that the callback was not replaced. So is there any way to do this?

Clarification:
What I actually want to do is to delete routes at runtime, but replacing callbacks with something that respond with say `404` would also do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear from your question, but it looks like you have both routes present in your code. If that is the case, then only the first one will be used.

If you are trying to set up some sort of dynamic routes (ie. replace the route handler completely after the application starts), I'm not sure that is possible in Express. According to [this comment](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2596#issuecomment-81353034) on deleting Express routes at runtime, it appears that the routes are optimized when the application is first initialized and there is no easy way to change them after that.

If you need a route to behave differently at runtime, the way to do it is in the route callback. For example:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // test something & respond accordingly
    if (req.query.someValue === 'do this') {
        return res.send('Hello world');
    }

    // otherwise, return a 404 error
    return res.status(404).send('No way, man!');
});
```